# I want to show images in the directory online but it not show the images properly how I can do this

Tags: php

I am trying to show images from online directory but images not shown properly and breaks what I can do to show these all images properly

```
 <?php 
 // Connects to your Database 
 include_once("connection.php");
 //read image directory     
$images_dir = '/home/qeplaho/public_html/image/';
function ListFiles($images_dir) {
    if($dh = opendir($images_dir)) {
        $files = Array();
        $inner_files = Array();
        while($file = readdir($dh)) {
            if($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file[0] != '.') {
                if(is_dir($images_dir . "/" . $file)) {
                    $inner_files = ListFiles($images_dir . "/" . $file);
                    if(is_array($inner_files)) $files = array_merge($files, $inner_files); 
                } else {
                    array_push($files, $images_dir . "/" . $file);
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($dh);`enter code here`
        return $files;
    }
}
echo "<table>";
foreach (ListFiles('/home/qeplaho/www/image/') as $key=>$file){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo"<td>";
    echo '<img src=\"$images_dir\" width="200" height="200"/>';
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
 echo "</table>";`<code>
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick:

```
$handle = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).'/pictures/');
        while($file = readdir($handle)){
            if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..'){
                echo '<img src="pictures/'.$file.'" border="0" />';
```

Comment: is there any other way to display all images from a folder on my website

Comment: i have changed my answer above.

Comment: i tried for this but it generates an error          Fatal error: Call to undefined function /home/qeplaho/public_html/image/() in /home/qeplaho/public_html/dm.php on line 4

Comment: is there any other way to make it